# scrapy selector fails when large lines are present response

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Originally encoutered by [github_user](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3077) when scraping [Amazon Restaurant](https://www.amazon.com/restaurants/zzzuszimbos0015gammaloc1name-new-york/d/B01HH7CS44?ref_=amzrst_pnr_cp_b_B01HH7CS44_438)
This page contains multiple script tag with lines greater then 64,000 character in one line.
The selector (xpath and css) does not search beyond these lines.

Due to this the following xpath '//h1[contains(@class, "hw-dp-restaurant-name")]/text()' to extract name of the restaurant returns empty even though there is a matching tag is present.Please help me how to fix this bug.Thank you in advance

Comment: Scrapy's selectors don't currently have the support for parsing documents like this one. I started working on adding it, but you'll have to parse your document using a different parser for now.

Comment: Thank you Sir for responding.Could you please help me out how can we fix this bug so that scrapy supports parsing of documents like this one as you are working on same.

Comment: If you really want to use code that hasn't been released yet, you can install the patched `lxml` library using `pip install git+https://github.com/stranac/lxml.git@HTMLParser_huge_tree` (you have to be able to install lxml from source). You'll also need a patched `parsel` library (which I haven't modified yet, but I believe simply adding `huge_tree=True` on this line should be all that's needed: https://github.com/scrapy/parsel/blob/master/parsel/selector.py#L42). Once you have those, you can install scrapy normally (I strongly recommend doing this in a virtualenv)

Comment: Thank You sir.The bug has already fixed by you [#](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/pull/261).